# Best Practice question for Javascript/Typescript class number vs. string

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, html-input

I am a newbie. I didn't realize that in my Typescript/React solution that even though I defined a property as a number and I made the input type be a "number" that whenever you put that state value into an input field that it will change it to string (unless you do anything to handle that).

In my case I am inserting the value initially from a xml soap call. The inner html for this item is "100.00". I'm declaring my class for this item (BaseFare) as a number and not a string and the state is initially set to 100.00 (as a number). It gets rendered on the form and the minute I make a change it changes back to string "199.00".

I do a calculation on the BaseFare in part of my code so I've had to do a parseInt on this function for it to handle what is now a string.

My question is ...
At what point do you decide to define it a string vs. a number. Doing the parseInt is fine. But I don't like the fact that the property is a number initially then changes to sting.
And then, because I think for anyone else looking at the code, they may think it is weird to have that property go from a number to a string, that if I am going to define it as a number then my handleChange function should definitely setState as a number so the value is always treated as a number.

Just wanted someone's opinion who is does this all the time...

What's the best most modern way to handle update a value from an input field and recording it as a number. I've seen valueAsNumber as a common way to deal with this...

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.valueAsNumber || e.target.value
    });
}
```

It seems that if it's a true number and I need to perform a calculation on it then the "proper" way is to define it as a number and keep it as a number. Yes?

Comment: Hello Richard, and welcome to SO, sadly such questions are not for SO, but rather on other Stack Exchanges forums. Here you shall post a direct problem that can be reproduced and answered (mostly) with code. Asking for opinions is sometimes insightful, but this is not the forum for that. I'm not downvoting, because the question is legit and you did your research, though I'm voting to close as opinion based ;)

Comment: Sorry I didn't know this - thank you ...

Comment: Don't worry, we're here to help ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM stores internally the value as a string, and what gets displayed to the user is a string.

So it's up to you to choose how you want to deal with it. On `<input type="number" />` you have the `valueAsNumber` as you found that can be used for the conversion, or you can do it yourself.

The only thing I believe that's important is to handle the conversion within the EventHandler.

Also to make things simpler, you can use a form library, such as [`react-hook-form`](https://react-hook-form.com/) that will [take care of that](https://react-hook-form.com/api#register), so you won't have to deal with that kind of details.
With it all you need to do is something such as:

```
const MyForm : FC = () =>
  const { register, watch } = useForm<{thatInput: number}>();

  const { thatInput } = watch();

  return (
    <...>
      <input type="number" name="thatInput" ref={register({valueAsNumber: true})} />
      <div>the value is: {thatInput}</div>
    </...>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `number` type in TypeScript supports floats

```
let inputValue: number = 3.14
console.log(inputValue)   //this is valid code
```

So then I guess your problem is with `input type="number"`

The number type has a `step` value controlling which numbers are valid (along with `max` and `min`), which defaults to 1. This value is also used by implementations for the stepper buttons (i.e. pressing up increases by step).

Simply change this value to whatever is appropriate. For money, two decimal places are probably expected:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01">
```

or

```
<input type="number" step="any">
```

Comment: This is a misleading answer. JavaScript, and by implication TypeScript, numbers do indeed support floating point but this has nothing to do with source of the error and it TypeScript has no impact here at all

Comment: Why is it misleading? the question was "At what point do you decide to define it a string vs. a number. Doing the parseInt is fine. But I don't like the fact that the property is a number initially then changes to sting"

He doesn't have to change it to a string and I've written why and how to implement

Comment: I follow you. Perhaps it's just the example that's confusing because `console.log` accepts any value and because `: number` annotation didn't impact the type of the declaration or the behavior of the program